# Stockable vs Consumable Products in Odoo

Tags: product, odoo-10

I would have thought this question would exist but I didnt see it in the dropdown.

In a coffee shop, prepared coffees and sandwiches and purchased bakery goods should be consumable, right?  Food and drinks in general are perishables and therefore dont stock well.  Coffee drinks and sandwiches prepared in house from purchased raw materials at the supermarket don't sound like stockable items because most are Make to Order and aren't stocked.

I thought maybe baked goods could be stockable because they last longer (1-2 weeks) in stock before they are discarded if unsold.  But I honestly see very little benefit in terms of stock management (reorders etc...) from setting those up as stockable.

Are there any tips or advantages of setting these up as one or the other that I should consider for the coffee shop?